# How to reinterpret_cast in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting

Our project depends on a C library that declares a general `struct`

```
typedef struct
{
  SomeType a_field;
  char payload[248];
} GeneralStruct
```

and a more specific one:

```
typedef struct
{
  SomeType a_field;
  OtherType other_field;
  AnotherType another_file;
  YetAnotherType yet_another_field;
} SpecificStruct
```

We have some examples of its usage in C++ and in some cases it's needed to cast the general one to the specific one like:

```
GeneralStruct generalStruct = // ...
SpecificStruct specificStruct = reinterpret_cast<SpecificStruct&>(generalStruct)
```

Is it something like `reinterpret_cast` available in Swift? I guess I could read the bytes from `payload` manually, but I'm looking for an idiomatic way

Comment: Take a look into UnsafeRawPointer. It has facilities for reinterpreting a raw pointer (originating from your original typed pointer) into a typed pointer (of your new type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer/2430863-withmemoryrebound) can be used

> ... when you have a pointer to memory bound to one type and you need to access that memory as instances of another type.

Example: Take the address of the general struct, then rebind and dereference the pointer:

```
let general = GeneralStruct()

let specific = withUnsafePointer(to: general) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: SpecificStruct.self, capacity: 1) {
        $0.pointee
    }
}
```

If both types have the same size and a compatible memory layout then you can also use [`unsafeBitCast(_:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast):

> Use this function only to convert the instance passed as x to a layout-compatible type when conversion through other means is not possible.
>
> **Warning:** Calling this function breaks the guarantees of the Swift type system; use with extreme care.

Example:

```
let specific = unsafeBitCast(general, to: SpecificStruct.self)
```