# How to reinterpret_cast with pointer to MTLBuffer Swift adaptation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, metal

I have an objective-c function block, that uses (for my understanding) some extra stuff and I would like to make this fully in Swift. Here is the original code, from which I've started.
(I was trying to convert this using Swiftify, but with no luck)
And this SO article unfortunately did not help: [How to reinterpret_cast in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972556/how-to-reinterpret-cast-in-swift)

```
- (void)updateBuffers
{
    id<MTLBuffer> noiseBuffer = _noise[[self frameIndex]];
    RandomSample* ptr = reinterpret_cast<RandomSample*>([noiseBuffer contents]);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < (NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE * NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE); ++i)
    {
        ptr->pixelSample.x = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->pixelSample.y = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->barycentricSample.x = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->barycentricSample.y = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->emitterBsdfSample.x = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->emitterBsdfSample.y = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->bsdfSample.x = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->bsdfSample.y = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->componentSample = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->emitterSample = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ptr->rrSample = uniformFloatDistribution(randomGenerator);
        ++ptr;
    }
    [_noise[[self frameIndex]] didModifyRange:NSMakeRange(0, [noiseBuffer length])];


}
```

I assume, the objective-c code fills the contents of the Buffer (using the for loop) with the contents from the Struct (RandomSample). NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE is in this case 64

And this is what I have so far:

```
    func updateBuffers() {

        let noiseBuffer = noise[Int(frameIndex())] // MTLBuffer

        var randomStruct = RandomSample()
        // Here I should have this ptr (pointer) that like on objective-c

        for i in 0..<(NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE * NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE) {

            randomStruct.pixelSample.x          = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.pixelSample.y          = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.barycentricSample.x    = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.barycentricSample.y    = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.emitterBsdfSample.x    = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.emitterBsdfSample.y    = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.bsdfSample.x           = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.bsdfSample.y           = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.componentSample        = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.emitterSample          = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
            randomStruct.rrSample               = Float.random(in: 0..<1)

        }

        // etc... etc...

    }
```

This is the RandomSample struct I want to reference, defined in a .h file (which is my Bridging Header)

```
struct RandomSample
{
    simd_float2 pixelSample;
    simd_float2 barycentricSample;
    simd_float2 bsdfSample;
    simd_float2 emitterBsdfSample;
    float componentSample;
    float emitterSample;
    float rrSample;
};
```

Instead of the `uniformFloatDistribution` I am using (within the Swift code)
`Float.random(in: 0..<1)`
which should produce more or less the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously I can't verify this on my machine, but you should be able to do something like this.

```
var noiseRaw = noiseBuffer.contents()
let samples = noiseRaw.bindMemory(
    to: RandomSample.self,
    capacity: NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE * NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE
)

for i in 0..<NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE * NOISE_BLOCK_SIZE {
    let sample = samples + i
    sample.pointee.componentSample = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
    sample.pointee.emitterSample = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
    sample.pointee.rrSample = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
}
```

Comment: It looks good. The only thing I am not sure of, is how to increment the Pointer in the for loop. in objective-c it uses ++ptr. How could I do this in Swift. (for the Moment I do this for the pointee attribute: => randomSamplePointer?.pointee.rrSample = Float.random(in: 0..<1)

Comment: @ZAY There a section called Performing Typed Pointer Arithmetic. That should help you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: How could I fill that pointer with the number of times the "for" loop runs? like in objective-c. But I have not found a kind of incrementer to do so. (like the ++ptr). In the Apple docs, they explain, how to access that stored memory, but I need to fill that Buffer with the RandomStruct X-Times. Like it's missing something in the "for" loop.

Comment: @ZAY I'm not sure I understand you but I updated my answer hoping that it does answer what I think you are asking. You increment your pointer using the \+\ operator.

Comment: This is great! You understood me. Just one last thing: should the "let sample = samples + i" be at the top of the for-loop (like in your answer) or at the end (like in objective-c code) ?

Comment: @ZAY It has to be at the top. After all, you can't define sample before it is used! Note that we are using "+" here, not "++" like in the objc solution. Also, if my answer is what you are looking for it would be great if you could mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!